# project dependency tree by using ant

Tags: ant, project, dependencies

I am trying to compile a j2ee project, and the solution file includes many source projects, libraries. some of source projects have dependency with other source projects. And this compile task will be done by using ant task. is there third party library allows me to do this task quickly?

next step after compiling will be export to ear file.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using [Grand](http://www.ggtools.net/grand/), [Ant2dot](http://ant2dot.sourceforge.net/#what) or [VizAnt](http://vizant.sourceforge.net/)