# check parent target of any target in ant

Tags: ant

Is there any way I can check the parent target of any target for example I have a target smoke-test

```
 <target name="run-smoke-tests" depends="deploy">
```

now I want to check the parent target of deploy in my ant script.

Comment: What do you mean by a "parent" target?  Do you mean the list of targets the `deploy` target depends on?  Do you want to traverse the whole dependency graph, or just get the direct dependencies?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any good tool to view and browse ant build file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7989706/is-there-any-good-tool-to-view-and-browse-ant-build-file) See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623858/project-dependency-tree-by-using-ant and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638544/ant-target-dependency-tree-viewer